# Pandas dataframe to filter rows by lookup a dictionary and compare based on the key

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset of trade records with `Type`, `Currency 1`, `Currency 2`, and `Days` columns. I would like to filter the records that should be excluded based on the following criteria:

If the `Type` is equal to ‘FO’, then the below logic should be applied:

- If the `Currency 1` is equal to ‘EUR’, ‘USD’, ‘JPY’, ‘AUD’, or ‘MXN’, the `Currency 2` is equal to ‘EUR’, ‘USD’, ‘JPY’, ‘AUD’, or ‘MXN’, and the `Days` is less than or equal to 2, the trade should be excluded.
- If the `Currency 1` or the `Currency 2` is not equal to ‘EUR’, ‘USD’, ‘JPY’, ‘AUD’, or ‘MXN’, and the `Day` is less than or equal to the `settlement period` for the currency pair or seven business days (whichever is earlier), then the trade should be excluded.

I also have a dictionary of `[SETTLEMENT]` value for each currency. The way to obtain the `settlement period` is the following:

- Where the `Currency 1` or the `Currency 2` is equal to ‘USD’, the settlement period should be equal to the `minimum` value of `[SETTLEMENT]`.
- Where the `Currency 1` or the `Currency 2` are both not equal to ‘USD’, the settlement period should be equal to the `maximum` value of `[SETTLEMENT]`.

The dictionary would look like such:
`settlement_dict = {'AED':2, 'PHP' = 1, 'AUD' = 2, ...}`

The logics are so embedded with one another and I have no clue how to use pandas to apply the logics to filter out the excluded trades. I would really appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: You could use numpy.where() to create conditional columns in your dataframe. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Comment: @DSteman thank you so much for the direction and conditional column make sense. One quick question: how would we be able to lookup the dictionary and compare the lookup results when writing the conditions for conditional column?

Comment: You can add an extra column where you translate the currency to a number based on that dictionary. Then use that column in your conditions as well.